# Как организовать чтение из файла С++

Tags: c++

Есть файл следующего содержания

> N=5, M=3, NB = 25
>
> LL(1) = 52, 65, 65, 14, 52, 102, 57, 17, 44, 77,  92, 84, 56, 89, 80,
>   42, 81, 97, 77, 19,  20, 30, 76, 67, 27, 44, 32, 48, 33, 55,  21, 87,
>   43, 17, 12, 28, 38, 22, 37, 45,  63, 26, 34, 73, 40, 16, 28, 57, 47,
>   50,  92, 41, 43, 61, 35, 44, 39, 64, 37, 28,  53, 101, 70,
>
> INA(1,1) = 1, 3, 8, 13, 20, 24, 28, 32, 37, 42,  46, 50, 54, 58, 62,
>   66, 70, 74, 78, 82,  86, 90, 94, 95, 98, 96, 97, 93, 88, 84,  80, 76,
>   72, 69, 65, 61, 57, 53, 49, 45,  41, 40, 36, 31, 27, 23, 19, 18, 15,
>   10,  6, 2,
>
> INA(1,2) = 275, 277, 278, 280, 279, 286, 292, 298, 305, 312,  320,
>   327, 334, 341, 349, 359, 371, 385, 384, 382,  381, 386, 387, 389, 403,
>   408, 427, 450, 476, 505,  539, 577, 615, 656, 704, 750, 797, 751, 703,
>   702,  714, 667, 625, 586, 547, 512, 482, 455, 431, 411,  395, 380,
>   367, 356, 346, 338, 331, 324, 316, 317,  309, 302, 295, 289, 283,
>
> INA(1,3) = 3021, 3069, 3127, 3128, 3131, 3130, 3193, 3256, 3309, 3363,
>   3364, 3414, 3465, 3468, 3518, 3517, 3515, 3562, 3599, 3633,  3669,
>   3703, 3702, 3670, 3632, 3598, 3561, 3514, 3516, 3467,  3416, 3417,
>   3366, 3311, 3312, 3313, 3314, 3315, 3367, 3418,  3469, 3519, 3563,
>   3600, 3634, 3636, 3635, 3671, 3672, 3674,  3638, 3602, 3565, 3521,
>   3471, 3420, 3369, 3317, 3262, 3197,  3134, 3074, 3023, 3025, 3022

и т.д.

как мне прочитать числа(M,N,NB), одномерные(LL[]) и двухмерные массивы(INA[][]) из данного файла?

Comment: А в чём проблема с тем, чтобы разобраться как в С++ происходит чтение из файлов?

Comment: Что такое N, M, NB и размер массивов как-то зависит от них?

Comment: это и есть размер некоторых массивов...но есть и такие массивы, размер которых не описан данным способом

Answer (score 6):

Это классический юз-кейс для парсеров. Вы можете поискать подходящие библиотеки через `c++ parser library`, но написать рекурсивный парсер вручную довольно просто.

Сначала вы должны составить грамматику языка в [EBNF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF), это будет что-то вроде:

```
input = header, {assignment};

header = "N=", integer, "M=", integer, "NB=", integer, "\n\n";

assignment = lhs, " = ", rhs
lhs = ll | ina
ll = "LL(", integer, ")"
ina = "INA(", integer, ",", integer, ")"
rhs = integer, ",", {integer, ","}, "\n\n"
```

Затем вам нужно перевести эту спецификацию в C++-код. Если вы делаете это вручную, то каждое правило будет функцией, скажем, такого вида:

```
some_type_t rule(std::istream &in, Data &data);
```

Каждое правило должно поглотить соответствующие символы из потока. Например:

```
int integer(std::istream &in, Data &data) {
    int i;
    in >> i;
    if (!in) {
        throw integer_error();
    }
    return i;
}
```

Такие парсеры называются рекурсивными, потому что правила вызывают друг друга (просто так или в цикле для правил, заключенных в фигурные скобки), например:

```
std::unique_ptr<LHSSpec> lhs(std::istream &in, Data &data) {
    char c;
    in.get(c);
    in.putback(c);
    if (c == 'L') {
        return ll(in, data);
    } else {
        return ina(in, data);
    }
}
```

В данном случае они сообщают об ошибках с помощью исключений (поэтому им также придется ловить исключения), чтобы выйти из цикла, что не хорошо, на самом деле), возвращают свои данные как возвращаемое значение функции, а правило `assignment` будет манипулировать параметром `Data &data`, непосредственно занося туда данные.

Это довольно неэффективный вариант, но он самый простой. Более эффективные варианты мало от него отличаются - они просто добавляют дополнительные переменные, чтобы лучше обрабатывать ошибки и передавать данные. Для более сложных языков я бы посоветовал делать кастомный стэк вместо использования рекурсивных вызовов, но в вашем случае это не нужно.

Возможно хорошей идеей будет не таскать с собой данные, а сначала сгенерировать абстрактное дерево синтаксиса (AST) языка, а потом отдельным шагом заполнить из него данные. В этом случае все функции будут возвращать `std::unique_ptr<ASTNode>`, где `ASTNode` - абстрактный класс узла дерева, определяющий виртуальные методы для его обработки; его потомки возможно также будут хранить указатели на другие узлы. Скорее всего, вы также захотите парсить весь `rhs` в один узел, хранящий вектор чисел, чтобы не создавать для каждого числа отдельный узел в куче.

Также хорошей идеей будет работать с вводом не напрямую, а обернув его в более высокоуровневый класс с методами вроде `readInteger`, `readLiteral`, `readRegex` и т. д., чтобы не дублировать каждый раз код при чтении литералов вроде "LL" или "INA", а также позволить большую гибкость в определении языка с использованием регулярных выражений.

UPD: если вы будете использовать потоки C++ для парсинга, то лучше отключить совместимость с stdio, для этого выполните где-нибудь в начале `main`:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

И после этого не используйте `printf`, `scanf` и пр.

Comment: А старый добрый yacc разве отменили?

Comment: @VladD я не могу с чистой совестью посоветовать то, в чем я сам не смог разобраться. Документация lex + yacc - полное УГ, особенно если нужен reentrant parser. Научите меня :)

Comment: Ну, у меня там проблем никаких не было, просто parser state оборачивается в класс.

Comment: @VladD как-нибудь попробую

Comment: @VladD еще я слышал про адовую отладку конфликтов LALR, для новичка это вряд ли будет приятным опытом

Comment: Вы имеете в виду shift/reduce? А где она не адовая?

Comment: Кстати: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Pure-Decl

Comment: @VladD в рекурсивных парсерах, где ее нет?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24806/discussion-between-alexei-averchenko-and-vladd).

Comment: Рекурсивный = LL?